# Laravel access to two level parent table in a relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have use laravel and i have this models and relationship between tables

Customers table

```
class Customers extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'contr_nom',
        'contr_cog',
        'benef_nom',
        'benef_cog',
        'email',
        'polizza',
        'targa',
        'iban',
        'int_iban',
        'cliente',
    ];

    public function claims()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Claims::class);
        }
        
    public function refunds()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Refunds::class, Claims::class);
    }

}
```

claims table

```
class Claims extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'dossier',
        'date_cla',
    ];

    public function refunds()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Refunds::class);
        }           
        
    public function customers()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Customers::class,'customers_id');
        }           

}
```

refunds table

```
class Refunds extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'date_ref',
        'status_ref',
        'disactive',
        'num_pre',
        'date_liq',
    ];

    public function services()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Services::class)
                ->withPivot(['services_id','services_amount','services_status']);
        }       
        
    public function claims()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Claims::class,'claims_id');
        }           

}
```

in controller i did this function

```
 public function addDateLiq2(Request $request){
 
      $date_liq = request("date_liq");

      $refunds = Refunds::whereNotNull('num_pre')->get();
      
      foreach ($refunds as $refund) {
        $status_ref= $refund->status_ref;
        if ($status_ref == 5){
          //send mail
          //I need to retrieve mail field from customers table
        }

        $refund->date_liq = $date_liq;
        $refund->save();

        if(!$refund->save()){
          App::abort(500, 'Error');
        }
      }

      return Response::json(array('success' => 'Date salvate massivamente correttamente!'), 200);

    }
```

that add a date in all records where num_pre is not null.
OK i wanted also send a mail but mail field is in Customer parent table....how  can i access it?
Thx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i seem i found a way with this in function addDateLiq2

```
      $data =  Claims::with(array('customers'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','email');
      }))
      ->whereHas('refunds', function($query) use($claims_id) {
        $query->where('claims_id', $claims_id);
      })
      ->first();
```

Comment: Where is `$claim_id` comes from? Is that magic variable?

Comment: I defined as $claims_id = $refund->claims_id;